# Which Schengen country can I apply to for long-term type C visas?

Tags: visas, schengen, nigerian-citizens

I always have this worry, and that includes, applying for a Schengen visa for longer periods. Like here is what I mean, I want to apply for a schengen visa for first time entry, and I would like to visit often and on, since my job allows me to (I work remotely for a company in Switzerland) and hence I do, I have a chance to enter a country time to time, without worries, problems etc.

Now the internet and living systems in Nigeria is completely another thing. I have lived in some countries, some include Rwanda, Togo, Benin Republic, Ghana Uganda and Senegal but I want to try something quite new.

The question is: Which Schengen country can I apply to at this time that can allow me to apply for long-term (multiple entry) visas for first entry?

Comment: What's your personal situation? Are you married, do you have kids? Do you own property in Nigeria? What's your financial situation (income, savings...). I'm afraid that Nigeria is usually among the countries with the highest refusal rates, and working remotely does not give you strong ties to your home country, so you'll need to demonstrate those ties, otherwise even a short-term single-entry visa has strong chances of being refused.

Comment: Living in all those countries can be considered proof that you do not have strong ties to any of them.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, travel plans (when, for how long and for how many journeys) determine the type and period of validity for a Schengen visitor (‘C’) visa.

Long term multiple-entry C visas valid for 1, 2, or 5 years are not usually given unless the applicant has previously been issued with a Schengen visa (not an airport transit visa) 3 times, or has previously held a long term multiple-entry visa.

If you’ve never had a Schengen visa before AFAIK there is nothing to stop you from applying to any country, but your application will be refused as you do not meet the eligibility criteria.

Comment: And you need to make sure that you are following the 90/180 clock on each visit

Comment: And when you apply for a visa, you must do so at the consulate of the country that will be your **main destination** of the first trip. If you plan a 10 day stay and 4 days are in Switzerland, 3 in France, 2 in Italy and 1 in Austria you must apply for the visa at the Swiss consulate.

Comment: One option could be if your Swiss employer invites you to come and work in Switzerland and arranged the needed paperwork.

Comment: @Willeke, i had wanted to try using Nomad visa as my second option, what u think?

Comment: @MrE For which country? Do you meet the eligibility criteria for a nomad visa eg income level? https://www.euronews.com/travel/2022/10/23/want-to-move-to-europe-here-are-all-the-digital-nomads-visas-available-for-remote-workers

Comment: @Traveller, Hungary.

Comment: @MrE, I am not familiar with that visa and can not advice you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a Schengen C visa does not allow you to work remote **from** those Schengen states. A bit simplified, you can visit on a C visa to *talk about what work you need to do*, but not to actually perform it. For that, you would need a national visa with a work permit, which are considerably harder to get.

Comment: Also note that if you are working for a Swiss Company the moment you are in Switzerland they may become liable for all the social security levies etc... So make sure they know about your whereabouts...